# How to get data from phpMyAdmin and use that data?

Tags: php, html, database

I have to get data from a database in phpMyAdmin and use it in some calculations. I believe my calculations are correct, but I need to know how to retrieve the data from the database. I am trying to get the number of gold medals, silver medals and bronze medals each country has received which are in a table called Country. I thought I could use a for loop, but the number of data is really high. I thought of doing

```
for ($i=0;$i>0;$i++){
}
```

but wasn't sure if that would go on forever and keep looping through the table over and over.
*Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks a lot*

I have already got the sql:
`$sql="SELECT country_name, gdp, population, gold, silver, bronze
FROM Country
";`

Comment: you need to run mysql queries for fetching data from database

Comment: PHP is perfectly capable of accessing MySQL databases. You don't need to use PhpMyAdmin as proxy. Is there something you haven't told us?

Comment: run a query to retrieve data

Comment: You need to connect to the database via PHP using `mysqli_()` or PDO extension

Answer (score 1):

> I have to get data from a database in phpMyAdmin

No you don't.

PhpMyAdmin is a tool for *accessing* a mysql database - the data is not **in** phpMyAdmin.

> I need to know how to retrieve the data from the database

[Learn / use SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

If you want to project the data into HTML, then there are lots of ways of doing that - PHP is a very good solution - but you still need to write your queries as SQL.

Comment: I have already got the sql: `$sql="SELECT country_name, gdp, population, gold, silver, bronze
FROM Country
";`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM('gold_medals') as 'sum_gold' ...
//fetch results, iterate through them
echo $row['sum_gold'];
```

This way? SUM() or COUNT() should work, depends on how you store the data

Comment: The OP is proposing what looks like a JavaScript loop as a tool to read a database. I don't think he'll understand your answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 4.*
Go to http://php.net and learn following functions:
mysql_connect()
mysql_select_db() and
mysql_query()
For PHP 5.*
Use mysqli_connect() and related function

Comment: Please DON'T. That extension is abandoned and will be removed from the language.

Comment: What language? you mean mysql_connect() and other functions are removed? PHP version is not specified here and it can be used for all the PHP version before 5.*!

Comment: Just open [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/mysql_connect) documentation and see the big red box on top.

Comment: You did not get my point! I am talking about PHP version is not specified in question.

Comment: Alright, I'll clarify my remarks... Your answer is valid if the OP is going to start a new development in 2013 using PHP 4. If the complete platform is outdated, the extension issues don't really matter. (BTW, the down-vote is actually not mine).